# row operations, swapping rows

Tags: linear-algebra

How I can justify that swap rows in an arbitrary matrix, can be done with other operations with rows?

This means that a matrix can be reduced without swapping rows.

Is this true for any matrix?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A row swap operation can be done with the following sequence of  the other operations, illustrated for rows one and two, with hopefully obvious notation
$$
{r_1\atop r_2}
\rightarrow
{r_1+r_2\atop r_2}\rightarrow
{r_1+r_2\atop r_2-(r_1+r_2)}=
{r_1+r_2\atop -r_1}\rightarrow
{(r_1+r_2)-r_1\atop-r_1}=
{r_2\atop -r_1}\rightarrow
{r_2\atop r_1}.
$$
The same sequence of operations will swap two distinct rows $r_k$ and $r_j$.