# row swapping not required in in obtaining row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [row operations, swapping rows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129706/row-operations-swapping-rows)

I am curious whether it is possible not to use row swapping to obtain row echelon form or reduced echelon form in every case.

I never heard of any theorem that proves or disproves this, so here's the question.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129706/row-operations-swapping-rows).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish row swapping by four successive other operations, so no explicit need.

Comment: right. stupid me..