# How to prove that to reduce $B$ to echelon form no row interchanges are needed?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that to reduce a matrix $A$ to row echelon form are necessary $n$ elementary operations $E_1,...,E_n$. Suppose that $E_{n_1},...,E_{n_k}$ are the permutation operations that are needed. How to prove that to reduce $B=E_{n_k} \cdots E_{n_1}A$ to echelon form no row interchanges are needed?

(my linear algebra book says it, but doesn't demonstrate)

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129706/row-operations-swapping-rows/129712).

Comment: It's sufficient to prove it when only one row swapping is necessary; for the general case use induction.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to ensure that no row exchanges are necessary is during elimination.   if an elimination step using pivot element i,j causes the element in i+1, j+1 to become zero, then you need a row swap because you just eliminated the next pivot point.

additionally, if any columns are linear combinations of other columns, you won't have a pivot in that column no matter how many row exchanges you do.